# Host an ASP.NET Core MVC application in an Azure Function

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-functions

I have tried searching for this online, but could not find an approach that works. There are a few helpful links to host a Web API but nothing related to a full fledged MVC app that consists of Controllers and Views. Azure currently does not have built in support for this. Hence, wondering if this is something doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this through the use of [Custom Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers). This [blog](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/azure-function-custom-handlers#:%7E:text=Custom%20Handler%20is%20a%20feature%20in%20Azure%20Functions,not%20be%20a%20language%20supported%20by%20Azure%20functions.) post goes into further detail on how to create a custom handler. Do note that this feature is currently in preview so support is limited.

Comment: Thanks Tom! The blog link was really helpful. They have explained custom handler for a webapi app, but with a few more code changes, I was able to get it to run an MVC app. If I get some time, I'll document the steps somewhere if anyone needs this info in future.